# Targeting elements within an element directive with Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

Consider the following view model:

```
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.person = {};
$scope.data.person.firstname = "";
$scope.data.person.lastname = "";
$scope.data.person.username = "";
```

and the following element directive:

```
<custom-form-directive ng-model="data.person"></custom-form-directive>
```

which contains three input tags to display the data. How do I use protractor to populate the input fields by targeting `ng-model="data.person"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on how you're getting data in/out of the inputs in the directive. However, in all cases you can chain together `element(<locator>)` calls to search for [sub-elements](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/locators.md#user-content-finding-sub-elements) of the directive:

```
var directive = element(by.model('data.person'));
var subElement = directive.element(by.<something>);
```

If you're using `ng-model` in the directive itself on each of the inputs, you can do something like:

```
var directive = element(by.model('data.person'));

// Assuming the inputs have attributes like `ng-model="firstname"` in the directive template
var firstnameInput = directive.element(by.model('firstname'));
var lastnameInput = directive.element(by.model('lastname'));
var usernameInput = directive.element(by.model('surnamname'));
```

and then on each call `sendKeys`

```
firstnameInput.sendKeys('Peter');
secondnameInput.sendKeys('Piper');
usernameInput.sendKeys('PickledPumpernickle');
```

If you're not using `ng-model` in the directive template, you can use other locators to find the sub elements, together with `get` if needs be, and depend on the order they're in the DOM

```
var inputs = directive.element(by.css('input'));
var firstnameInput = inputs.get(0);
var secondnameInput = inputs.get(1);
var usernameInput = inputs.get(2);
```

However, I suspect none of the above will work if you have `replace: true` specified in the directive, as it depends on the original element, with the `ng-model` attribute, being in the DOM.

Answer (score 5):

This is exactly what the evaluate method is for: http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ElementFinder.prototype.evaluate

```
element(by.model('data.person')).evaluate('data.person.firstname = "yourvaluehere"');
```

I assume by "targeting the model" you want to change the controller's value and have the ng-model directive update the view, rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to build something like a "pageObject" (see https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md) for your `custom-form-directive` directive.  This object will understand how the directive maps to primitives that Protractor will understand (e.g., specific input fields).  It should take a locator so its callers can pass in the how to find the directive on the page, but the object should handle everything after that.

```
var object = new customFormDirectiveObject(by.model('data.person'));
```

depending on how your directive works you'd do something like:

```
object.setName(first, last, user);
```

or if its more dyanmic maybe something like this:

```
object.setName({firstname: first, lastname: last, username: user });
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This looks promising and I will report back once I test it out.

Answer (score 0):

With a few helper function you could do it rather easily. The helper object just wraps protractor and makes it a little more sane and safe to use. Especially when running on remote systems.

```
var helper = {
  getElement: function (selector) {
    return element(by.css(selector));
  },

  resolveSelector: function (selector) {
    var el;
    if (typeof selector === 'string') {
      el = self.getElement(selector);
    } else {
      el = selector;
    }
    return el;
  },

  waitForElementClickable: function (selector) {
    var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
    var condition = function () {
      return self.waitForElement(el).then(function () {
        return self.isElementEnabled(el);
      });
    };
    return self.wait(condition, 15000, 'Element not clickable. (' + selector + ')');
  },

  setElementValue: function (selector, value) {
    var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
    return self.waitForElementClickable(el).then(function () {
      el.click().clear().sendKeys(value);
    });
  },

  getElementValue: function (selector) {
    var el = self.resolveSelector(selector);
    return el ? el.getAttribute('value') : '';
  }

}
```

Then you can just use regular CSS selectors to set your values:

```
helper.setElementValue('[ng-model="data.person"] input:nth-child(1)', '1st Input Value');
helper.setElementValue('[ng-model="data.person"] input:nth-child(2)', '2nd Input Value');
helper.setElementValue('[ng-model="data.person"] input:nth-child(3)', '3rd Input Value');
```

And you can check for expected values with something like this:

```
expect(helper.getElementValue('[ng-model="data.person"] input:nth-child(1)')).toEqual('something')
```